# How do I sort Python Dictionary using values which are of data type list

Tags: python

So here is a dictionary

```
orders = {'Square': ['blue', 134684.0, 1026, 539], 
          'Circle': ['red', 284405.0, 442, 539], 
          'Triangle': ['red', 21699.0, 167, 392], 
          'Pentagon': ['green', 75563.0, 587, 332]}
```

And the second element of the value is area for example area of Square is 134684. I am supposed to sort whole dictionary using that area value. Like wise Circle should come first.

I tried using

```
sorted(orders.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

but I cant implement it in my code very well.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort the items of the dictionary, just add another accessor (`[1]`) to your `key` function, like this:

```
d = {'Square': ['blue', 134684.0, 1026, 539], 'Circle': ['red', 284405.0, 442, 539],
     'Triangle': ['red', 21699.0, 167, 392],
     'Pentagon': ['green', 75563.0, 587, 332]}

result = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1], reverse=True)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[('Circle', ['red', 284405.0, 442, 539]), ('Square', ['blue', 134684.0, 1026, 539]), ('Pentagon', ['green', 75563.0, 587, 332]), ('Triangle', ['red', 21699.0, 167, 392])]
```

Comment: Great, but you need to convert the output to dictionary with `dict()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to access `x[1]`:

```
print(dict(sorted(orders.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1], reverse=True)))
```

To get it into the original dict:

```
orders = dict(sorted(orders.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1], reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
{'Circle': ['red', 284405.0, 442, 539],
 'Square': ['blue', 134684.0, 1026, 539],
 'Pentagon': ['green', 75563.0, 587, 332],
 'Triangle': ['red', 21699.0, 167, 392]}
```

Answer (score 1):

dataset = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][1])
print(dataset)